# How do I add the console in the quick view panel in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: console, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

**This seems to be missing in the Edge:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's because it's not optional, it always exists in the bottom drawer. You can toggle it via Esc key or `Ctrl~`

Comment: as you can see in my first screenshot, there is no console in the quickView in my Edge. Whereas it is there is in Chrome

Comment: Yes. Just press the hotkey to toggle the bottom drawer and you'll see the console. It's always present there. Note that the drawer won't be shown if the active devtools tab is already Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wOxxOm said, the console tool is default and already exists in the Quick View toolbar, so you don't need to add it. Please refer to [Open tools from Quick View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/experimental-features/focus-mode#open-tools-from-quick-view) for more configurations.

Based on your description, I suggest you could check if the "**Show Console tab in main panel and drawer**"option is unchecked (like the picture shown).

1. Open dev tools
2. Click Customize icon (three dots) on upper right.
3. Click Settings.
4. Confirm if the "Show Console tab in main panel and drawer" is checked under **Console** section in **Preferences** tab.

[image]

If the issue persists, you could check you Edge version and update to the latest to check if there is Console Drawer.

Comment: as you can see in my first screenshot, there is no console in the quickView in my Edge. Whereas it is there is in Chrome (2nd Screenshot)

Comment: Hi @Pratyush, I have updated my answer. Please help check if it works for you.

Comment: Yes. that was unchecked in my dev tools settings. Thank you! this solved my issue.